# Why does the variable which stores dialog box not closing application in UFT?

Tags: wpf, vbscript, hp-uft, uft14

I recorded the sample flight application with UFT recording feature and surprisingly, the below mentioned code does everything apart from closing the application, that is x.close does not close the application.

---

```
Set x = WpfWindow("HPE MyFlight Sample Applicatio")
x.WpfEdit("agentName").Set "John"
x.WpfEdit("password").SetSecure "59533cbffdbec3d9d0ff"
x.WpfButton("OK").Click
x.Close
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting. This mostly happens when the properties of the window have changed after logging in. Is the application navigating to correct page? Compare the properties at login page and after logging in.

Comment: Hi Mithilesh, I am not getting any error. It is just not closing the application. If I replace x with `WpfWindow("HPE MyFlight Sample Applicatio").Close` in last statement, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before Closing the wpfWindow, set the object reference again as shown below.

After OK button is clicked, the window has "refreshed"(should I say?) and you are still using the existing reference to that window.

```
Set x = WpfWindow("HPE MyFlight Sample Applicatio")
x.WpfEdit("agentName").Set "John"
x.WpfEdit("password").SetSecure "59533cbffdbec3d9d0ff"
x.WpfButton("OK").Click
Set x = WpfWindow("HPE MyFlight Sample Applicatio")    'Added this line just after clicking on OK button but before closing the wpfWindow
x.Close
```